# How to "try" a python program

Tags: python

and sorry for this question. I'm a Ruby developer and I have no knowledge of Python. Now I must write a parser plugin for a Kodi Media Center add-on and the parser is written in python.

I have several example to follow and also a guide so I can write something, the problem is that I want to try my parser on my computer instead of loading it on my Kodi Media Center.

I have a .py file with some function inside like this:

```
def get_events():
    try:
        source = mechanize_browser(base_url)
    except: source = ""; xbmcgui.Dialog().ok(translate(40000),translate(40128))
    if source:
        items = re.findall('<div class="base custom" align="center"(.*?)</center></div><br></div>', source, re.DOTALL)
        number_of_items= len(items)
        for item in reversed(items):
            data = re.compile('<div style="text-align: center;">(.+?)</div>').findall(item)
            try:
                check = re.compile(" (.+?):(.+?)").findall(data[-1].replace("color:",""))
                if not check and "Online" not in data[-1]:pass
                else:
                    data_item = data[-1].replace("<strong>","").replace("</strong>","").replace('<span style="color: #008000;">','').replace("</span>","")
                    url = re.compile('<a href="(.+?)">').findall(item)
                    teams = re.compile('/.+?-(.+?).html').findall(url[0])
                    try:
                                                match = re.compile('(.+?) (.+?) (.+?):(.*)').findall(data_item)
                                                import datetime
                                                from utils import pytzimp
                                                timezona= settings.getSetting('timezone_new')
                                                d = pytzimp.timezone(str(pytzimp.timezone('Europe/Moscow'))).localize(datetime.datetime(2014, 6, int(match[0][0]), hour=int(match[0][2]), minute=int(match[0][3])))
                                                my_place=pytzimp.timezone(pytzimp.all_timezones[int(timezona)])
                                                convertido=d.astimezone(my_place)
                                                fmt = "%d %H:%M"
                                                time=convertido.strftime(fmt)
                                                addDir("[B][COLOR orange]("+translate(600012)+time+")[/COLOR][/B] "+teams[0],url[0],401,os.path.join(current_dir,'icon.png'),number_of_items,True,parser="liveevent",parserfunction="streams")
                    except:
                        if '<span style="color: #000000;">' not in data_item:
                            addDir("[B][COLOR green]("+data_item+")[/COLOR][/B] "+teams[0],url[0],401,os.path.join(current_dir,'icon.png'),number_of_items,True,parser="liveevents",parserfunction="streams")
                        else: pass
            except: pass
```

It's similar to ruby so I can read it and I think I can also rewrite it, but I need to know how can I "launch" this file on OSX adding some debug lines to check if everything is ok before creating the add on package.

In ruby I can use `ruby filename` and I can add some `pry` and some `puts`, but with Python I have no idea.

Comment: I don't suppose you thought to try `python filename`?

Comment: It should have been faster to google "python print" than write all this. Start it with `python filename` and use `print` for...printing basically.

Answer (score 0):

To run a python program you can do:

```
python filename.py
```

And to print a variable:

```
print(variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well probably using python is really easy indeed.

To print a variable in python:

```
print(variable)
```

Then to execute the program:

```
python filename.py
```

If you're a windows user in some cases it would work as the following:

```
py filename.py
```

Comment: 'how can I "launch" this file on OSX' would imply they are not a Windows user.